# Write JS inside material ui styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to put some conditional logic inside mui styles

Currently using inline style, which works

```
<div className={classes.form} style={{alignItems: ((Code.length>10 || Description.length>100) ? 'start' : 'center')}}> 
... 
</div>
```

But want to do the same thing inside mui styles, which gives error

```
// Code and Description state
...

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
form: {
    alignItems: {(Code.length>10 || Description.length>100) ? 'start' : 'center'}, //Code not defined
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a props the the `useStyles` hook and use it like this:

```
const classes = useStyles(props);
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
form: {
    alignItems: props => props.Code.length>10 || props.Description.length>100 ? 'start' : 'center',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never mentioned how `Code` and `Description` are defined, but you can pass `props` to `makeStyles`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  form: {
    alignItems: props => (props.Code.length > 10 || props.Description.length > 100) ? 'start' : 'center'
  }
}));

// Usage
const classes = useStyles(props);
```